# Выбор города реализация

Tags: php

Делаю сайт с мультивыбором городов, возник вопрос, как лучше хранить id текущего города?
В базе данных или в куках? Какой способ наиболее правильный? Склоняюсь больше к тому, что бы хранить id текущего города в куках.

Comment: это конечно же зависит от того, что ваш сайт из себя представляет. но если вы не увидели надобности хранить это в БД, то да, лучше использовать куки.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, зачем вам эта информация.
Если вы хотите что бы отображение последнего выбранного города было для удобства пользователя то храните в куках. Так при большом кол-ве пользователей меньше нагрузка.
Если вы планируете использовать эту информацию для отображения доп. данных, заносите в БД, и куки одновременно.